# What does the below phrase in the lstm blog mean? - Data Science

Tags: deep-learning, lstm

I am a newbie to data science. I was reading this [blog](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-rnn-models-for-human-activity-recognition-time-series-classification/)

When I was half way through, I came into this sentence

> Further, each series of data has been partitioned into overlapping
>   windows of 2.56 seconds of data, or 128 time steps. These windows of
>   data correspond to the windows of engineered features (rows) in the
>   previous section.

What does 'series' means here and what is window partitioning?

Further I would like to ask all the data science enthusiasts there,What do I lack here.Is it comprehension or logical skills needed .What can I do to improve upon this.I encounter such doubts often and what I do is search for the terms I dont understand or leave it and get ahead.When I search for the terms I get broad answers leaving me more confused.If i leave it like that I dont understand the rest.What should I do here?I cant post every small doubts in stack exchange.**It would be great If you could share some light on this as well.**

Answer (score 0):

I think, with "series", the authors refer to time series data in their dataset. In this case, it should be x, y, z, angular velocity and maybe other features for each participant.

*"Splitting data into fixed windows of 2.56 seconds (128 data points) with 50% overlap."* I would translate to:
Every 2.56 seconds aggregate each series of the data over the next 5.12 seconds.

You can imagine windowing basically as a timestamp-based data aggregation technique that is often used for stream data processing to reduce data and fix granularity of the data. The [stream analytics windowing function documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-window-functions) contains visualizations, which should help you to understand what is meant. I think, in the blog, the authors mean what Microsoft calls "[hopping windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/hopping-window-azure-stream-analytics)".

I read that windowing is a [time series feature engineering](https://machinelearningmastery.com/basic-feature-engineering-time-series-data-python/) topic. So maybe, it might help, if you learn more about feature engineering.